# I try to position a divider in the NavBar at a distance of 25 pixels from the bottom, in Flutter app. How to look right on any device screen?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, divider

```dart
Widget BuildMenuItems(BuildContext context) => Column(
 
    children: [
 
      const SizedBox(height: 8),
      Divider(thickness: 1.6, color: Colors.blue),
 
      ListTile(
        leading: Icon(Icons.home_outlined),
        title: Text("Home page", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15)),
      ),
   
 
      ListTile(
        leading: Icon(Icons.home_outlined),
        title: Text("Example page 2", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15)),
      ),
 
     
      ListTile(
        leading: Icon(Icons.home_outlined),
        title: Text("Example page 3", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15)),
      ),


      //The interesting part starts here
      Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 300.0, bottom: 25),
        child: Divider(thickness: 1.6, color: Colors.blue),
           
        ),

 
    ],
    
  );
```

I want to look right on any device screen, divider to the buttom.

Answer (score 0):

You can use third party packages like Sizer (https://pub.dev/packages/sizer).
In your case the code might look like:

```
import "package:sizer/sizer.dart";
Widget BuildMenuItems(BuildContext context) => Column(
children: [
  const SizedBox(height: 8),
  Divider(thickness: 1.6, color: Colors.blue),
  ListTile(
    leading: Icon(Icons.home_outlined),
    title: Text("Home page", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15)),
  ),
  ListTile(
    leading: Icon(Icons.home_outlined),
    title: Text("Example page 2", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15)),
  ),
  ListTile(
    leading: Icon(Icons.home_outlined),
    title: Text("Example page 3", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15)),
  ),
  //The interesting part starts here
  Padding(
    padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 300.0, bottom: 2.h // it takes 2% of screen height.),
    child: Divider(thickness: 1.6, color: Colors.blue),
    ),
 ],
);
```

Or you can simply use MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.02 to take the 2% of the screen height.

Comment: Thank you, I found a solution that can help other developers. Footer view https://pub.dev/packages/footer